# VIM Shortcuts just don't work a lot of the time

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm using VIM on a macbook pro in iterm2. Some of the shortcuts I set, and even some of what is supposed to be default, just don't work a great deal of the time. For example, I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","

map <leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

When I'm editing my `.vimrc`, this works fine, and opens the NERDTree buffer window, but when I'm editing in any other repo, I get `Couldn't find any definitions for this`. I've tried several other shortcuts, such as `<C-n>` that also had similar effects.

Also, I've attempted to do visual block commenting by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, then using <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to highlight a block, then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> and the comment character. It never works. I've also tried just pressing <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> then <kbd>i</kbd>. A number of different configurations. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like Jedi Vim interfering, since pluginless Vim doesn't have the error you're reporting, and I'll bet it only happens if you open a Python file. First, check that Jedi Vim doesn't have a colliding mapping. Second, unless you know what you're doing, always use `noremap` instead of `map`. As for your visual block, the sequence that you should be doing is: Ctrl-v, select, Shift-i, #, Esc (you did not say whether or not you pressed Esc).

Comment: thanks! that's pretty useful. I do have jedi installed. How would I check it's mapping?

Comment: and for block commenting, just tried that sequence, and have tried it in the past. Doesn't work either :/

Comment: `:verbose map <leader>n` while you are in a Python buffer might give you a hint what is in fact happening. Regarding visual block, you'd need to describe in detail how exactly is it not working (as in, what is happening instead). Also, check whether you can reproduce my sequence when you start `vim -u NONE` - if so, again one of your plugins is squawking your parrot.